# Django field select and text entry problem

Tags: python, django

I want to allow the user to expand (add additional text in the same field) on the selected option for a Django model field.

I have a working select option field on the form but it does not allow addition or expansion of the selected item.  This is as expected.  In the real world i want to add some information to the option selected.  Can this be done?

```
class MedicalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    OPTIONS = (
                ("COLD", "Common cold"),
                ("FLU", "Flu strain"),
                ("VIRUS", "Unknown virus"),
                )
    illness = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label='What is wrong?',  widget=forms.(choices=OPTIONS))
```

I would like the user to describe the symptoms for example after selecting the option. I allow 60 chars for the illness field.

Comment: You need ChoiceField, why not use it ?

Comment: Great.  I think your proposal will work.  Many thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This was suggested in a comment, but your situation sounds exactly like you want a `ChoiceField`

```
OPTIONS = (
                ("COLD", "Common cold"),
                ("FLU", "Flu strain"),
                ("VIRUS", "Unknown virus"),
                )

illnesses = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTIONS, widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

This provides a drop-down select element rendered in the form with your options provided as choices.

Then you can use a `CharField` to allow the description of symptoms. Is this not what you're looking for?

```
description = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label='What is wrong?', required=True)
```

In terms of actually morphing a `CharField` to simultaneously be a select option as your provided code looks like a bit, it is not possible with base functionality provided by Django, and I'm not sure I'm actually understanding the idea of what you want with that.

If you need the submitted data to be stored in a single database column, simply combine the output from the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary after you call `if form.is_valid()`